# Porting Android mobile application to WeChat Mini Program

Tags: android, wechat-miniprogram

Are there any tools that can help me port my Android mobile application to a WeChat Mini Program? If not automated tools, is there any documentation as to best practices for manually porting my Android mobile application to a WeChat Mini Program?

Comment: is your app a native android code?Some tools can develop android/ios apps and wechat-miniprograms concurrently like uniapp,but can't transform.

Comment: Android app is native...